# How can I send http command in vbs

Tags: vbscript

We have PBX controlled via http. When I send

```
http://10.20.30.11:8888/switch?name=lukas&destination=84022&source=84021
```

in address line Firefox, command is working correctly (tel. line is conected from line 84021 to line lukas 84022.
I try send the command via vbs:

```
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")

On Error Resume Next

URL = "http://10.20.30.11:8888/switch?name=lukas&destination=84022&source=84021"

http.open "GET", URL, False
http.send 

Set http = Nothing
```

Bat this script isn't working.
Could you help me, please?
Thank for your answer.

Comment: When you say it isn't working what happens exactly? Do you get an error? Maybe worth checking `http.status` for the HTTP Status Code and `http.responseText` for the response to see why it's failing.

Comment: Exactly PBX don't connect line from 84021 to 84022. Script does not report any error. I red HTTP GET link, I tried CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") method and CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") method, bat PBX still don't connect line. http command sent from address line firefox not returnet any message.

Comment: You could start by removing `On Error Resume Next`, and then maybe you will get some error message.

Comment: I tried run script without "On Error Resume Next". It is same. Script not returnet any error code.